# How to remove certain files from a pull request with allot of commits?

Tags: git, version-control

To generalize, suppose I have a project with the following directory.  How would I ultimately remove file2.txt after pushing and doing a pull request?

```
app/someFolder
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
```

Suppose my commits are these

```
Commit 1       
  file1.txt
    Hello World
  file2.txt
    Cool, Superb
  file3.txt
    December 2
```

git add .
git commit -m "commit 1"
git push --set upstream origin someBranchOnRemote

```
 Commit 2  
   file1.txt
     Hello World
     Boss Bass
```

git add .
git commit -m "commit 2"
git push

```
 Commit 3
   file3.txt
     December 3
```

git add .
git commit -m "commit 3"
git push

So if I were to do a pull request the files would look like this

```
file1.txt
  Hello World
  Boss Bass
file2.txt
  Cool, Superb
file3.txt
  December 3
```

Now how would I update the pull request so I can have file2.txt not be included?  Suppose the hashes are hash1, hash2 and hash3.  The final output I want in the pull request would be

```
file1.txt
  Hello World
  Boss Bass
file3.txt
  December 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: you want `git rebase -i` followed by `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease`.  But read the following.

First, a side note: Git itself does not have "pull requests"; those are features of certain hosting sites such as GitHub and Bitbucket.  They tend to work similarly on each hosting site, but each site has its own quirks and behaviors here.  You may have to adapt this answer for whichever hosting site you're using.

With that out of the way, a PR is a request you make to someone that they merge (or "fetch and merge" = "pull") some commit(s) you've made.  In Git, you don't really merge a *branch:* you actually merge *commits*.  The commits that you will merge, when you run `git merge`, are those from some chain of commits, as ended by the *last* commit in that chain.

That is: commits form chains.  Each commit *in* a chain remembers the raw hash ID of its predecessor commit.  We say that a commit *points to* its parent commit, and we can draw that like this:

```
... <-E <-F <-G <-H
```

A *branch name* then simply provides the raw hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, from which Git will find all the previous commits:

```
...--E--F--G--H   <-- branch
```

When you go to *make* a pull request, you:

- begin by forking and/or cloning some repository, so that you get all the *commits* that someone else has;
- create a new branch name, so that you have a name pointing to the *last* commit that's also one of *their* commits;
- make new commits so that your branch name advances.

For instance, let's say that their commits go up through (and then stop at) the commit I was drawing above as `E`.  (By the way, I only stopped drawing arrows between commits out of laziness: commits always point backwards, so any time you see a connecting "line", it's really a backwards-pointing "arrow".)

That is, they have, in *their* repository, some sequence of commits:

```
...--D--E   <-- somebranch
```

You now have, in your repository:

```
...--D--E    <-- origin/somebranch
```

You create a *new branch name* pointing to commit `E`:

```
...--D--E    <-- my-fancy-new-feature, origin/somebranch
```

Now you make *new commits* while "on" this new branch:

```
...--D--E    <-- origin/somebranch
         \
          F   <-- my-fancy-new-feature (HEAD)
```

This is your "hash 1", or "commit 1", that affects three files.  Commit `F` has *all the files* in it, as all commits always have a full snapshot of every file, but the files *in* commit `F` are all the same as all the files in commit `E`, except for the three that you changed.  (Git cleverly de-duplicates *identical* files, so that this doesn't take very much space, either.)

Now that commit `F` exists, you make another new commit `G`:

```
...--D--E    <-- origin/somebranch
         \
          F--G   <-- my-fancy-new-feature (HEAD)
```

This is your "commit 2", which changes only file `file1.txt`.  Commit `G` still has every file, it's just that its copy of `file2.txt` matches that of commit `F`; its copy of `file3.txt` matches that of commit `F`; and all its other files match those of commits `F` *and `E`*.

Finally, you add commit `H`:

```
...--D--E    <-- origin/somebranch
         \
          F--G--H   <-- my-fancy-new-feature (HEAD)
```

In commit `H` you've replaced `file3.txt` with a modified file; `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` matches the copies in commit `G`, and so on.

That brings us to your question again:

> ... how would I update the pull request so I can have `file2.txt` not be included?

Git works on the basis of *commits*, not files, and your PR says *please merge commit `H`*.  To change this, you must either:

- somehow change commit `H`, or
- change the PR so that it lists some other commit hash ID, not `H`.

It's literally impossible to change *anything* about *any commit*, ever, so the first idea is right out.

Whether it's possible to change the PR so that it lists some other commit, depends on the hosting site.  If the hosting site is particularly obnoxious, you might have to *close* this PR, and open a new one later.  But GitHub at least will let you update the PR quite simply.

Your first task, though, is to come up with *new commits*.  You don't want `file2.txt` changed, but it was different in commit `F` (vs commit `E`), so commit `F` itself is bad in some way.  This means you need a new replacement for commit `F`.  Let's call this `F'` to indicate that it's a lot *like* `F`, but it will have a different raw hash ID.

To get commit `F'`, we want to "copy" commit `F` without quite committing yet.  We'll start by checking out commit `E`.  We could create another new branch name, but we could also use Git's "detached HEAD" mode, like this:

```
...--E   <-- HEAD, origin/somebranch
      \
       F--G--H   <-- my-fancy-new-feature
```

Now we'll run, say, `git cherry-pick -n` and give Git commit `F`'s hash ID, or something equivalent: `my-fancy-new-feature~2` for instance.  Git will copy the effect of `F` but not commit anything yet—we'll have some work in progress that we can commit—and now we have a chance to *undo* the change to `file2`, with, e.g., `git restore`:

```
git restore -SW --source=origin/somebranch file2.txt
```

A quick `git status` and `git diff --cached` will show that we've now retained the updated versions of `file1.txt` and `file3.txt`, but gone back to the original `file2.txt` from commit `E` as found by the name `origin/somebranch`.

We can now run `git commit` to make `F'`:

```
       F'  <-- HEAD
      /
...--E   <-- origin/somebranch
      \
       F--G--H   <-- my-fancy-new-feature
```

Commit `G` affects `file1.txt` only, so we can just copy it wholesale, with `git cherry-pick`, which will not only figure out what it changed and apply it, but also make a new commit, re-using the original commit's message:

```
       F'-G'  <-- HEAD
      /
...--E   <-- origin/somebranch
      \
       F--G--H   <-- my-fancy-new-feature
```

You might wonder why we *copy* `G` to `G'`, rather than just using `G` itself.  The answer is simple: *nothing about commit `G` can ever change*.  The arrow coming out of `G`, pointing to `F`, is part of `G`.  It can't change!  Commit `G` will forever point back to commit `F`, never to commit `F'`.  So we *have to* copy `G`.

Also, commit `G` has the wrong copy of `file2.txt` in it, of course, which would also force us to copy it—but *anything* that forces us to copy the commit, forces the whole thing.  Note that when we do "copy" `G` with cherry-pick, Git compares the snapshot *in* `G` to that in `F` to see what *changed*.  Since `file2.txt` in this pair-of-commits did not *change*, Git won't *change* `file2.txt` in `G'` vs `F'`.  So `G'` will have the same `file2.txt` as `F'`, and `F'` has the same `file2.txt` as `E`.

Now, for the same reasons, we need to copy `H`, which we can do with one more `git cherry-pick` command.  The result is:

```
       F'-G'-H'  <-- HEAD
      /
...--E   <-- origin/somebranch
      \
       F--G--H   <-- my-fancy-new-feature
```

Now that we have the right *commits*, all (all?!) we have to do is to get the *name* `my-fancy-new-feature` to point to `H'` instead of `H`.  We can do that in various ways, such as `git checkout -B my-fancy-new-feature` or `git switch -C my-fancy-new-feature`.  The final result here will be:

```
       F'-G'-H'  <-- my-fancy-new-feature (HEAD)
      /
...--E   <-- origin/somebranch
      \
       F--G--H   ???
```

What happens to the `F-G-H` chain, that Git used to find by looking at the name `my-fancy-new-feature`?  The answer is: nothing *happens* to it.  It's still *there*.  It's just that now, it goes unused.  [These aren't the <s>droids</s> commits you're looking for](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=532j-186xEQ), so we just make sure that these aren't the commits we *find*.

We now have the right commits, locally, in *this* repository.  Now we have to get them to the hosting site, and get the hosting site to update the pull request.  To do that on GitHub, we just push the new commits to GitHub, telling the Git over on GitHub to *replace* the `F-G-H` commits in its repository with our new `F'-G'-H'` chain.

Git in general is greedy for commits, so if we just run a regular `git push origin my-fancy-new-feature`, they—the Git over on GitHub, operating on your repository over there—will *reject our attempt to do this*.  They will say, in effect, *No! If I do that I'll lose the F-G-H chain!*  (As with our own repository, the commits won't be *gone*, they just won't be findable by the *name* `my-fancy-new-feature` any more.  But that's enough for them to reject the request.)  You'll likely get a suggestion that you `pull` (i.e., fetch and merge) the commits from GitHub: they don't realize that they got them from you in the first place, and that you're telling them *these are the new and improved **replacements** so you should ditch the old ones in favor of these new-and-improved ones*.

To *make* them realize that, you need some kind of forced-push (not Star Wars style "force", but just the regular English-language meaning).  Git has several kinds and you can use any of them here, but `--force-with-lease` has a safety feature (that shouldn't matter here: if it does, something has gone not-according-to-plan, and the safety feature detects that) and is generally the way to go.

#### Making this easy(ish)

The sequence above has lots of Git commands in it, many of them tricky (I didn't show the full commands for multiple reasons).  We can reduce that to a smaller number of much-less-tricky commands using `git rebase -i`.  There's still one big bit of trickiness though.

Running:

```
git switch my-fancy-new-feature
git rebase -i origin/somebranch
```

is how we start.  The rebase operates on the *current branch*, so we begin by checking out `my-fancy-new-feature` (you can use `git checkout` or `git switch` here, or do nothing if you're already on it).

What rebase does is:

- list out commits to copy (hash IDs);
- use Git's *detached HEAD* mode to begin copying; and
- start cherry-picking.

Once it's all done, it fixes up the detached HEAD by moving the branch name to the last of the *copied* commits (`H'` in our case).  So that automates a lot of the hard work.

Rebase in general is what we use when we have some commits that we mostly *like*, but there is something *about* those commits that we *don't* like.  Since nothing about any existing commit can *change*, rebase works by *copying* the commits.  The new copies *can* be changed along the way, before we commit them.

The *interactive* rebase in particular gives us more opportunities for change.  A plain `rebase` just copies everything without giving us a chance to fix stuff, which is useful for *moving* commits—for taking a chain like this:

```
          A--B--C   <-- topic
         /
...--o--o--o--o   <-- mainline
```

and copying it to:

```
          A--B--C   ???
         /
...--o--o--o--o   <-- mainline
               \
                A'-B'-C'  <-- topic
```

so that the commits now come at the *end* of the mainline, instead of sprouting from an earlier point.  That's not what we want here: we want to *change some of the files* in one of the commits.

So, interactive rebase, instead of just planning out all the cherry-picks and then starting them, writes out an *instruction sheet*.  This instruction sheet *lists* the cherry-picks, using the word `pick` for each one:

```
pick hash1  subject
pick hash2  subject
pick hash3  subject
```

Then, once the instruction sheet is written, `git rebase -i` *opens an editor on the instruction sheet* so that we can *change the commands*.

In our case, we don't want to just pick commit #1 as-is.  We want a chance to *change* it.  So we will change `pick` to `edit`.  We do want to pick #2 and #3 as is, so we'll leave those alone.  Then we write out the instruction sheet and exit the editor,<sup>1</sup> to return to the cherry-pick action.

Having changed the first `pick` to `edit`, Git will cherry-pick the first commit but then stop to let us fix it up.  There's one thing that's particularly tricky here: Git has actually *made* a temporary commit at this point, so when we do fix it up, we have to run `git commit --amend`.<sup>2</sup>  We can now do our `git restore` as I described earlier, then run `git commit --amend`:

```
git restore -SW --source origin/somebranch file2.txt
git commit --amend
```

(note: `--source=origin/somebranch` and `--source origin/somebranch` work the same way here, so you can use either one).

Once we're done fixing up that edit-able commit, we tell Git to resume the rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```

This will finish off all the remaining cherry-picks, then re-arrange the branch name and re-attach our `HEAD` to our branch, and now we have what we wanted:

```
       F'-G'-H'  <-- my-fancy-new-feature (HEAD)
      /
...--E   <-- origin/somebranch
      \
       F--G--H   ???
```

We're now ready to run:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin my-fancy-new-feature
```

and if we're talking GitHub, the "update the PR without closing and re-opening" is now done.

We used a total of five or six Git commands, about half of what we needed earlier, and we didn't have to do anything tricky except for the interactive rebase "edit" step.  Everything else is pretty straightforward here.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some editors don't *exit:* you start them up early and then they hang around forever.  Examples include many cases of Emacs, Sublime, and Atom.  If you're using one of these editors, you have to make them interact well with Git; that's a matter for that particular editor, but most of these editors these days have a `--wait` flag that arranges all of that to work right.

<sup>2</sup>The `--amend` flag seems to change a commit, contradicting the claim above that we can't change any commit.  The dirty secret here is that `--amend` *doesn't* change a commit.  Instead, it just makes *yet another* commit.  So when we use `--edit` we generate extra, rather pointless, "trash" commits.  But commits in Git are so small and cheap that it's better to do this than to avoid it.  Git will eventually clean up after itself, though this generally takes more than a month.  The cleanup / janitorial stuff that Git does is a bit slow, but sweeping up a month's worth of trash in 5 minutes, rather than cleaning up every bit of trash right away, is actually a highly practical tradeoff.

Comment: I will have to try the git rebase strategy.  What I've been doing the past, which is annoying was to checkout the commit before the problem commit and then cherry pick the next commit I want, do a git reset --soft HEAD~ which unstages everything, then remove the file(s) I want, then cherry pick the rest of the commits.  What you described seems to be easier than the workaround I was doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements, I would just delete the file, make a new commit out of it and push it to your branch. That way there would be a 4th commit in the PR removing the file and the final result would be as you say.

Comment: (Now, if you have *additional* requirements like previous three commits having to be in some specific state, you should update the question with that information.)